# What is the best database to use with Grails in an enterprise application?

Tags: database, hibernate, grails

I realize this has flame potential, please refrain. That being said, I'm interested in what databases people have used with Grails. What positive experiences and what horror stories are out there?

I love MySQL, but there are a few significant bugs that are impacting me between Hibernate and MySQL, particularly as it pertains to index creation. So I guess my question is really, what is the most stable database for integration with Grails? Or what database has the fewest bugs with respect to Grails?

Or what database has the widest use in conjunction with Grails? I also realize that these questions are somewhat orthogonal and opposing. Anyway, I'd like to open it up to discussion.

Comment: You should really be asking what databases are better used with Hibernate, because that's really what matters when it comes to Grails.  I'm curious what MySQL issues regarding indexes you are having.  I've built several large grails applications on MySQL and haven't ran into any issues.

Comment: yes, thanks - notice that I tagged the Q with hibernate... the bug is related to creating indexes from gorm. see: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-1458

Comment: Ah, I have run into that problem before.  I've just submitted to using SchemaExport rather than letting Gorm generate my tables.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/454286/Groovy/Grails-Schema-Export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Hibernate in enterprice apps since version 1. My personal chart is

1. Oracle: fast stable lot of dba knows it and hao to tune performace backups end so
2. SQLServer: same as above (but not as fast as Oracle)
3. DB2: not so easy to use with hibernate(I got several issues with date and char datatype)
4. MySQL: not so easy to manage or find professional support (may be different for you) but Hibernate stuff works great.

Answer (score 1):

As Gregg said, this is a hibernate question - Grails does all it's DB interaction via that (except for any custom SQL you write).

The only problem you might hit is with the GORM DSL not correctly creating any tricky hibernate mappings you require for a particular DB (especially if it's a legacy one). But GORM is pretty mature these days and I personally haven't hit any issues lately.

We run MySQL in production on a public web application and it has been fine. We've also deployed 'enterprisey' apps on top of Oracle which also went well except for a couple of issues with id generator configuration if I recall correctly. But I think those have been fixed in the latest Grails version.

In summary, go with your gut feel based on previous experience with hibernate.

cheers

Lee